# Ionic 3 page reference in app.component

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have recently upgraded to ionic 3 implementing the `IonicPageModule` for navigation. The `push` and `setRoot` works for all navigating however i am stuck at the trying to reference the pages in the `app.component.ts`

Normally i would reference the page from the import like so

```
this.rootPage = user ? ProgramsPage : LoginPage;
```

Where `LoginPage` and `ProgramPage` are declared in the `app.module.ts`

However in the new angular 4 / ionic 3 setup references to the "pages" are referenced with strings without an import in the related `page.ts` and seemly integrated with the `navCtrl`'s push and set

I have tried

```
import { LoginPageModule } from '../pages/login/login.module';
```

But that does not make sense.

I figured the whole point of creating modules per page was to firstly enalble lazy loading but also minimize the `import` code on pages without having to create a config export class.

And the thing is you cannot declare the `LoginPage` twice and seeing as though it is already declared as a module through the `IonicPageModule` one cannot add that export class again.

*So just wondering how do you reference a ionic 3 page module when you want to apply logic?*

Comment: can you give a use case where you would explicitely use page object other than nav?

Comment: how do you mean " other than nav" ?

Comment: [NavController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) has the api to get the page views from its stack... I meant other than pushing/popping from it.. Or maybe I misunderstood your query?

Comment: For logic operations like in the question . if the there is a user set the page   to `x` else set it to `y`. This is a subscribe event based on logic not a user navigation based event. I also have guard rails that use the page component which dont work any more because of the update

Comment: `this.rootPage = user ? 'ProgramsPage' : 'LoginPage';` this way does not work?

Comment: No you cant do that because then your `app.component.ts` file has to be module with the `IonicPageModule` import .. which is cant because it is already attached to the main entry ngModule. It cant be its own module and be tightly coupled to the `app.module.ts`

Comment: Its weird because if you `ionic start foobar sidemenu --v2` they are still doing it the old way without lazy loading, which is bazaar because the `ionic generate page foobar` generates lazy loading based navigation (O.o)

Comment: I havent updated my cli to v3 to test it... maybe they havent updated all the templates to v3 yet

Comment: "you cant do that because then your app.component.ts file has to be module with the IonicPageModule" this I did not get.. you just have to import the starting page modules in ngModule right? then you can use the strings as I suggested to set `this.rootPage`.

Comment: You cant though because then i get an error , because the page modules import member is the class and you cant access the strings through that class member, well i dont know how to but it doesnt work

Comment: this is a nice question... you can check my proposed answer

Answer (score 0):

I came across an article that implemented close to what you really wanted; though it talked more about cloud functions but at the beginning it tried to solve your  problem in a very fashionable way. Take a look https://javebratt.com/firebase-cloud-functions-profile/

Answer (score 0):

if your pages are being declared as:

```
/* imports and stuff here ... */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-user',
  templateUrl: 'user.html'
})
export class UserPage { /* constructor, your code & else ... */ }
```

or generated using the ionic-cli by running: `ionic g page NewAppPage`
you will be able to use the string page name instead of using the page object (that also requires you to import the page).

Take a look at https://www.javascripttuts.com/ionic-3-new-pages-lazy-loading/ , it may help you understand a little bit more about lazy loading and pages inside the app component.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this all seems to be fixed with the latest version.